# How to properly cancel a Task on ViewModel-deactivation with ReactiveUI?

Tags: c#, mvvm, system.reactive, reactiveui

In my MVVM application, when a ViewModel gets activated, a Task gets started that establishes a network connection and could take some time to complete. This Task is cancalable:

```
private async Task ConnectAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    ...
}
```

I'm using `IActivatableViewModel` to start it on ViewModel-activation like that:

```
// Constructor:
public SomeViewModel(...)
{
    this.WhenActivated(disposable => {
        Observable.StartAsync(ConnectAsync);
    });
}
```

Now what is the recommended method to cancel this long-running Task when the ViewModel gets deactivated before the Task completes?

I came up with this:

```
this.WhenActivated(disposable => {
    Observable.StartAsync(ConnectAsync).Subscribe().DisposeWith(disposable);
});
```

Is this the right solution or is there a better one?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think that is ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, the code like you show in your code snippet looks good. However, probably worth moving the `ConnectAsync` method call to a `ReactiveCommand<TInput, TOutput>` ([docs](https://www.reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/commands/)). If you do this, you get such perks as the ability to subscribe to `ThrownExceptions` and `IsExecuting` observables, and then display some loading indicators or error messages to keep your users informed about what the app is doing. Also, following the pattern described [here](https://www.reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/commands/canceling#canceling-via-another-observable), you can cancel that `ReactiveCommand<TInput, TOutput>` via another command or event. Cancelation via an event would look like this:

```cs
// ViewModel.cs
Cancel = ReactiveCommand.Create(() => { });
Connect = ReactiveCommand
    .CreateFromObservable(
        () => Observable
            .StartAsync(ConnectAsync)
            .TakeUntil(Cancel));

// View.xaml.cs
this.WhenActivated(disposable => {
    this.Events() // Launch the long-running operation
        .Loaded
        .Select(args => Unit.Default)
        .InvokeCommand(ViewModel, x => x.Connect)
        .DisposeWith(disposable);
    this.Events() // Stop that long-running operation
        .Unloaded
        .Select(args => Unit.Default)
        .InvokeCommand(ViewModel, x => x.Cancel)
        .DisposeWith(disposable);
});
```

Here, I assume `ConnectAsync` is a method accepting a cancelation token and returning a `Task`. In order to enable the `this.Events()` magic, you need to either use [Pharmacist](https://github.com/reactiveui/pharmacist), or to install one of the [ReactiveUI.Events](https://www.reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/events/) packages. But anyway, your option looks good as well if you want to rely on `WhenActivated`, don't need `ThrownExceptions`, `IsExecuting` etc. If you'd like to use commands and rely on `WhenActivated`, then modify the `View.xaml.cs` code:

```cs
// View.xaml.cs
this.WhenActivated(disposable => {
    Connect.Execute().Subscribe();
    Disposable
        .Create(() => Cancel.Execute().Subscribe())
        .DisposeWith(disposable);
});
```

We aren't disposing of the subscriptions returned by `Execute()` because they'll get disposed anyway when the commands complete their execution. Hope this helps! ✨

Comment: Thank you very much, I like this solution, it's way more powerful and cleaner. But because I'm using Avalonia UI, I'll probably have to wait for https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/pull/4535 being released in the next preview.
Which event can I use in case of Avalonia? Loaded/Unloaded doesn't seem to exist there? AttachedToVisualTree?

Comment: `WhenActivated` uses `AttachedToVisualTree` under the hood, so in your case `this.Events()` isn't required I suppose. Also, `this.Events()` will become available if you install `Pharmacist` like this https://github.com/worldbeater/ReactiveMvvm/blob/main/src/ReactiveMvvm.Terminal/ReactiveMvvm.Terminal.csproj#L7

Comment: Also `Avalonia.ReactiveUI.Events` should be available in a Avalonia nightly build feed https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/wiki/Using-nightly-build-feed